# Deploying a Machine Learning Model by developing a web application without sharing the patient data i.e. without sending the data to the server

Tags: javascript, python, json, machine-learning, web

I have a machine learning model that has been trained using patient data. Now I want to deploy this model via a web application, so that doctors can use it!
I know I can use Flask and Django for this but there is a problem that the patient data should not be sent anywhere because of data privacy.

The patient data entered in the application should only remain on the end user's device as all data processing should be done locally in the application or web browser environment.

I know it is possible to do this with native app. But I want to avoid a native app as much as possible. I would like to have the model as a web page.

Please does anyone have an idea of how I can deploy a Machine Learning Model, so that the data entered by the user for the model to make the prediction also happens on the user's browser? I.e. no server, no anything like that. Everything (Input of new data, Predictions ) has to happen on the end user's device

Thanks in advance